# Multiple splits in Ms Sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, split, csv

I have string of format with two delimiters  `‘|’` pipe  and `‘,’` comma

```
'1,100,12345|2,345,433|3,23423,123|4,33,55'
```

And have to insert into table columns as below

```
+-----+---------+--------+
| seq | invoice | amount |
+-----+---------+--------+
|   1 |     100 |  12345 |
|   2 |     345 |    433 |
|   3 |   23423 |    123 |
|   4 |      33 |     55 |
+-----+---------+--------+
```

Please help
Thanks
Prathibha

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I could get the first split by '|'

Comment: A need of split often indicates a lack of the database design. You should normalize it and use tables to link these values.

Comment: Is this string something generated by your application? If so you can pass these in using table valued parameters rather than a delimited string.

Comment: For each of the resultant string after split by '|', split again by ',' and insert the results into the table. By the way, it would have been better if you had told everybody if you want sql for this or code in some other language.

Answer (score 1):

One way

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(MAX) = '1,100,12345|2,345,433|3,23423,123|4,33,55'

DECLARE @x xml = '<r><c>' + 
                 REPLACE(REPLACE(@S, ',','</c><c>'),'|','</c></r><r><c>') + 
                 '</c></r>'


SELECT x.value('c[1]','int') AS seq,
       x.value('c[2]','int') AS invoice,
       x.value('c[3]','int') AS amount
FROM @x.nodes('/r') x(x)
```